# Calc shows title bar only when opening CSV (in Compiz)

Tags: compiz, libreoffice, mate, ubuntu-mate, 19.04

This issue comes up after I upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04. The LibreOffice installed is v6.2.2.2 20(Build:2).

When I open a CSV (any CSV), it prompts the formatting dialog (as usual),

[image: formatting dialog]

after I press OK, only the title bar is shown, without the rest of the program.

[image: title bar only]

It does accept input; it prompts save dialog after I type something.

No issue with ODS. Not related with multi-monitor setup (issue still persists even with a single monitor).

One workaround is to open the file from Calc (rather from file manager), but even then I can only open one CSV. Second CSV would have this issue.

**Edit:** Issue still persists even after reinstallation (with purge).

**Edit:** I got this message from the shell when I try to open the CSV with `--safe-mode` parameter:

```
(soffice:3575): Gtk-WARNING **: infinite surface size not supported
```

**Edit:** Apparently caused by Compiz. No issue after I switch to Marco (GPU or not). But excluding Calc from window decoration (in Compiz) doesn't resolve it though.

**Edit:** Resolved using LO 6.1. This issue also affect LO 6.3 Calc (snap-installed), including ODS file. I started using OnlyOffice.

Comment: have the same issue. it seems to be https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 + Gnome Flashback + Compiz. I "solved" it by downgrading to LibreOffice 6.1.5, available in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-6-1 or in LibreOffice's website.

Comment: Alternatively, I also tried replacing libreoffice-gtk3 with libreoffice-gtk2, which works but it doesn't integrate well with the system's theme (mate 1.20 + plata + paper icon). LO 6.1 (from official website) works better, but still not appear as good as the shipped's. Small caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround - tested works with 6.4 and 7.0

For me, the window only appeared invisible if it was maximized when I closed it previously. As long as it was a "restored" window, it would open normally the next time.

As such, I set the "Window Rules" -> "Size Rules" in compiz to always open (class=libreoffice-calc) with Width and Height values that were large enough to nearly fill the screen, but not extend past the screen edge.

Optionally, you can disable maximizing it in "Window Rules" -> "Matches" by adding (class=libreoffice-calc) to the "Non maximizable windows" box, although this also prevents some of the "Grid" behavior for this window (edge snapping no longer works, but corners do).

Not perfect, but at least it removes a step, and you can easily have multiple csv files open.